# How Qt supports graphs implementations?

Tags: qt

In Qt how the implementation of graphs i.e plotting of graphs is supported?
Do we have any Qt classes or libraries for it as there are for other features ?
The graph here to be drawn is a linear graph drawn between Current and voltage.

Comment: In terms of Qt, your question doesn't make any sense as there aren't any graph widgets nor graph containers (as in DAG, etc.).  Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I get what you're asking (and @cbamber85 is completely right in his comments) then you might want to look at [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) It has several graph drawing widgets including spline classes which allow for interpolation of data points.

Comment: ya sure...Actually my project is a I-V characteristics & peak power analyzer for solar panels. The analyzer draws an I-V curve with measured value and extrapolate this curve with other two curves which are based on standard test conditions and ideal conditions. Now for the UI of this device we have to use qt, as I am aware that graph implementations are possible in qt but do not know anything about the interpolation of graphs in qt....

Comment: Qt framework does not prevent you doing interpolation when you are implementing your graph drawing. However, Qt is not a graph drawing widget. You need to do the work by youself or use a 3rd party graph library, and then the question should be addressed to that library.

Comment: oh ok...thanks so much Roku....was looking forward to such answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As extensive as Qt is and as many areas as it's trying to cover, you have to realize that Qt is not a one stop shop for your GUI projects. With that said, the answer to your question is simply "Yes". Sure that's possible. But not as native functionality within Qt. (Unless someone would prove me wrong here. I'm unaware of such functionality) Qt provides all the crayons you could ever wish for, but does not always do the drawing for you.

Luckily however, there are those who have developed various add-on libraries using Qt as a base. For example there is [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). As they say themselves: *"The Qwt library contains GUI Components and utility classes which are primarily useful for programs with a technical background."*

They provide a number of widgets for plots with all kinds of line styles to fit certain data sets. I'm sure that either you'll be able to find something which fits your needs in there. Or if not, you can extend its functionality to fit your needs.

P.s.: I am assuming here that you wish to plot your data in the end. If this is not the case, this might be overkill.

Comment: I did not close your question. As you might have been able to read, it was a moderator ( @casperOne in this case). I would guess this decision was made based on flags, but I simply don't know. Also, you have just commented on my answer. Or at the very least the best answer I could give, given your question. I have put some effort into this, explaining to you what Qt is and isn't and that you might find what you're looking for within Qwt. A suggestion you thanked Shobi for. All in all I would suggest you improve your questions and show some appreciation for those who try to help you out.

Comment: Even though I told you the exact same thing in the comments more than an hour before... Ah well, glad you got an answer you liked.

Comment: Then improve your questions. Comments are not meant personally. They tell you there is something wrong with your questions. The links [given here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/161198) might be of use to you. Read them. We all help you without asking anything in return if your question is good. The risk of asking questions that might not be a good fit for SO is that at one point you might be automatically blocked. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, go ask on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) what is "not good" about your questions and how you could improve them.

Comment: One more thing: No need to change the accepted answer to mine after accepting Shobi's. If his answer helped you out, that's fair enough.

Comment: both were same just you elaborate well so....

Answer (score 1):

for graph interpolation and extrapolation you can use qwt libraries..

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/